# Restore Trash Item using ScriptingBridge in Mac OS X via PyObjC

Tags: macos, pyobjc, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to figure out a way to restore (Put Back) Trash Item using ScriptingBridge via PyObjC.

There isn't enough documentation [here](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/documentation/pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge/api-notes-ScriptingBridge.html)

```
from AppKit import NSURL
from ScriptingBridge import SBApplication
targetfile = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(f.realpath)
finder = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier_("com.apple.Finder")
trash_items = finder.trash.items()
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

PS:
I'm using Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with `AppleScript`-able applications from Python, you will almost always find it easier to use [appscript](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/appscript/) rather than Apple's `ScriptingBridge` or `PyObjC`.  One way to do it:

```
from appscript import *
# move file to trash
app("Finder").move(mactypes.File(f.realpath),to=its.trash)
# get names of all items in the Trash
app("Finder").trash.items.name.get()
# move file x.txt from Trash to Desktop Folder
app("Finder").trash.files["x.txt"].move(to=its.desktop)
```

The trick is getting the right Apple Event reference to the desired files and folders.  It may be even easier to cheat a bit and get the path to the trash folder and use standard file system operations on it:

```
>>> app("System Events").trash.POSIX_path()
u'/Users/nad/.Trash'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

But, is it possible to move the Trash item to the same location where it came from (just Like 'Put Back' Option) ?

Comment: The `Put Back` option is new in OS X 10.6 (classic Mac OS users would say it restores a missing feature).  Somewhat surprisingly, it appears that the information about `put back` paths for all items moved to the Trash is maintained in one file `~/.Trash/.DS_Store` (http://www.appleexaminer.com/MacsAndOS/Analysis/SLPutBack/SLPutBack.html).  Its contents does not appear to be exposed through the Apple Events interface of the Finder or System Events so, unless there is some other documented API to access it, it should be considered an OS X private API that should not be relied upon.  Sorry!